# How to properly link against openblas

Tags: c++, linker, lapack, blas, openblas

I am declaring LAPACK functions inside a `extern "C"` block and then using them in my C++ code. According to my limited understanding about how BLAS/LAPACK works, linking against my blas library should be enough. However, `-lblas` does not suffice and I am forced to do `-llapack`.

Why does this happen? I am using `openblas`, hence `-lblas` should be enough. What am I missing here? I would like to understand how does linking against BLAS/LAPACK work.

**Minimal working exmaple:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    void dpptrf_(const char *, const int *, double *, int *);
}

int main() {
    const char UPLO = 'L';
    const int N = 3;
    double AP[6] = {5,1,1,5,1,5};
    int INFO = 0;

    dpptrf_(&UPLO, &N, AP, &INFO);

    for (auto elem : AP)
        std::cout << elem << ", ";

    return 0;
}
```

**Reference to dpptrf:**

[netlib.org/dpptrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga1fa71e503eabce2514406ba9d872ba63.html#ga1fa71e503eabce2514406ba9d872ba63)

**Command to compile:**

```
g++ main.cpp -lblas          // Does not work
g++ main.cpp -lblas -llapack // Works
```

**Additional information:**

```
> pacman -Q blas
openblas 0.3.5-1

> pacman -Q lapack
lapack 3.8.0-2

> pacman -Q gcc
gcc 8.2.1+20181127-1
```

Comment: _"According to my limited understanding about how BLAS/LAPACK works, linking against my blas library should be enough."_ Why do you think so? It obviosly depends on the lapack library.

Comment: You are right. `nm -DC libblas.so  | grep dpptrf` produces no results, whereas `nm -DC liblapack.so  | grep dpptrf` has the symbol. I guess this question can be closed/removed

Comment: Don't worry, your question is already closed righteously.